# Using quartz scheduler in Tomcat with jobs in multiple WARs

Tags: java, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I am working with a mid-size Java 9 project that has to run multiple Quartz 2.3.1 jobs in multiple WARs within a single Tomcat 9 environment.

1. Should these jobs be handled with a single JDBCJobStore and run with a single Scheduler? I am curious because there aren't any examples around the web for running jobs from multiple WARs.

I have created a ClassLoadHelper in which the various Webapp classloaders register / unregister themselves on deploy / undeploy and it loads the Job classes from their classloaders.

2. If the scheduler is started while some WebApps are deploying I get the following exception:

```
org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery.
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:697) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:539) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler$1.run(QuartzScheduler.java:564) [quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [?:?]
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger 'TestTrigger' for 'TestJob' job:Couldn't retrieve job because a required class was not found: org.myorg.test.TestJob
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1228) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doUpdateOfMisfiredTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1042) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverMisfiredJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:991) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:871) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$1.executeVoid(JobStoreSupport.java:843) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3780) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3778) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3864) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:839) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:695) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:?]
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job because a required class was not found
```

That is ok, the second webapp is being deployed. However the Scheduler startup is stuck, it does not start other jobs whose classes are available. It is not trying to start the missing jobs later. Is there a way to put the jobs with missing classes into ERROR state and continue the scheduler startup? Or the scheduler is to be started after all webapps are deployed? How to handle jobs that are to be started on Tomcat shutdown?

4. If the jobs are not in WAITING state (for example paused or error), the misfired jobs recovery is skipped. Is it ok to pause all triggers in a SchedulerListener's schedulerStartup() method in order to make sure the scheduler startup does not fail? And webapps should pause/resume their jobs on deploy/undeploy?
5. The jobs should be disabled / enabled by the user, and this setting must be preserved even if the job is in ERROR or PAUSED_becauseClassIsMissing state inside the scheduler. Do I need some external administration to store it?
6. A possible solution is that the ClassLoadHelper could return a NoOpJob if the job class is not found. Do I break anything besides the misfired trigger recovery with this approach?

Comment: Different applications (WARs) can share JDBCJobStore, but should use own scheduler names - different names will protect jobs against execution attempt by foreign applications